# Grounded vs. Preferred Semantics (Dung)

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

How does Dung's Grounded Semantics framework work in practice? I got this from slides of an AI course but can't figure it out:

[image: Grounded vs. Preferred Semantics]

Grounded Semantics is said to minimize amount of arguments IN (green) while Preferred Semantics tries to maximize this. I understand the Preferred Semantics but don't see how all arguments would be defensible according to Grounded Semantics. Wouldn't C always be OUT and D always IN?

If anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Logic in artificial intelligence is an enormous field with clear and well-defined mathematical content (which, in particular, applies to argumentation frameworks, as in this question). I strongly disagree with the vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the paper at the link,

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/21a1/a88328f8e274816a70061666ee2ded6f8235.pdf

to be helpful here.  There is a definition on page 6 of what it means to defend an argument, and, it seems to justify the statement of your diagram.  What is more cryptic with your graphic is that the grounded semantics is $\emptyset$ to the best that I can tell -- no nodes are highlighted with green.  So, while node C is defensible, it is not defensible with a non-conflicting set of arguments.  Nodes A and B conflict with one another.  So, the grounding set must be empty.

Hopefully, you will find an expert.  I am just a guy who can read definitions.

Thanks for your question -- interesting subject.